# How do I view and adjust all camera settings at once in Nokia Pro Cam?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, camera

I'm using a Nokia 920 with the Amber update. When I installed Pro Cam, I'd seen screenshots where all the different camera settings were visible on the screen at once, and could be edited by moving the sliders across the different rings:

**What I would like to see**
[image: What I would like to see]

However, I never saw that on my phone: the different settings were available, but via a much smaller menu at the top of the screen, where it's much harder to see what the current settings are:

**What I actually see**
[image: What I actually see]

(These are both screenshots from Nokia's website, rather than images I've made myself.) At first, I assumed that the first view was only available to people with newer phones than mine (eg the 928, 1020, etc...).  This made me depressed because I wanted to have the first view, as it seems a superior interface.

Today I took a few photos and then put my phone in my pocket without locking the screen.  When I took it back out, it had changed mode from the second Pro Cam interface, to the first.  So my Nokia is capable of displaying the camera settings in the way that I want - but I can't see (anywhere in the settings or the tutorial for the application) how to switch back and forth between the two display modes.

Has anyone else experienced this?  How do you switch?

Comment: I had missed that too. Needed to get in touch with support team. Just do what @HaLaBi said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piece a cake, swipe your finger from right to left (starting from the edge) and all pro settings will be shown at once ;)

[image: pro cam]